# FPU trigonometry functions calls from C++

Tags: c++, assembly, masm, fpu

I'm trying to use FPU with *masm* under VS2013 (Win10 x64) to get sine and cosine. The header is:

```
#pragma once

extern "C" double fpu_sincos(const double a_d_angle, double& a_sin, double& a_cos);

extern "C" double fpu_sin(const double a_d_angle);

extern "C" double fpu_cos(const double a_d_angle);
```

These functions get called from regular Visual C++ code.
While the first function works properly and I DO get corrent values via parameters by reference, but the other two functions **give bad results**. The .asm file contains:

```
    PUBLIC  fpu_sincos
    PUBLIC  fpu_sin
    PUBLIC  fpu_cos

    _TEXT   SEGMENT
    a$ = 32
    fpu_sincos PROC
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm0
        sub rsp, 24
        fld QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        fsincos
        fstp QWORD PTR [r8]
        fstp QWORD PTR [rdx]
        add rsp, 24
        ret 0
    fpu_sincos ENDP
    _TEXT   ENDS

    _TEXT   SEGMENT
    a$ = 8
    fpu_sin PROC
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        fld QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        fsin
        fstp QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        ret 0
    fpu_sin ENDP
    _TEXT   ENDS

    _TEXT   SEGMENT
    a$ = 8
    fpu_cos PROC
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        fld QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        fcos
        fstp QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        movq    xmm0, QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
        ret 0
    fpu_cos ENDP
    _TEXT   ENDS

    END
```

I've spent some time fighting with the issue, but I'm not familiar with Assembly language so I couldn't have won :/ 
Need some help! And it would be great if someone explained it line by line.

Thanks.

Comment: You declare the functions `extern "C" ` but you delare the arguments as references which don't exist in C. That can't be right, can it?.

Comment: @user2079303 well, it actually works

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the behaviour is not defined by the standard. If the documentation of your compiler on your platform says that  it's OK, then I guess it's OK if you never use another compiler or platform where it's not OK. Which I guess you won't since you use masm.

Comment: @user2079303 Ok, thank you. Let's now forget about the sincos() function then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operands for storing `xmm0` are in the wrong order.

Change both

```
movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR a$[rsp]
```

to

```
movsd   QWORD PTR a$[rsp], xmm0
```